# Failed to register layer: How to recover docker from deleting btrfs subvolums?

Tags: docker

[Update: this turned out to be a non-issue, please see my comment below]

So, when I try to pull an image with "docker pull IMAGE", I'm getting this error:

```
failed to register layer: stat /var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes/a8a6006af1d850f2dbb7052630731907fe6a2938af338a3c1a0f683e7ba178bf: no such file or directory
```

It started by not being able to run the docker daemon, because of a "no space left on device" problem on my machine. Since deleting larger files didn't help, I started to remove btrfs subvolums with

```
for subvolume in /var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes/*; do btrfs subvolume delete $subvolume; done
```

(that I got from here https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3894)

Now I'm getting the above error.

I'm looking now for ways to recreate the docker machine from scratch, starting on a fresh btrfs filesystem.

Docker info

```
Server Version: 17.12.0-ce
Storage Driver: btrfs
Build Version: Btrfs v4.9.1
Library Version: 102
```

Comment: Nevermind, all I had to do was to restart the daemon, simply sudo systemctl restart docker.

Comment: That did not help in my case, so I'd still be interested in a solution.